# When is the pointer &x created in function(&x)?

Tags: c, pointers, unary-operator

When are the pointers to `a` and `b` created?
In the code below, I only declared/initiated `a` and `b`.
But the function `swap` treats them with `&a` and `&b` which are pointers.

My question is, 
Are the pointers to a and b created at the same time with `int a` and `int b`?

Or are they created when `swap` function was called with arguments `&a` and `&b`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Pointers to variables aren't created, they just exist as a consequence of the way the language is. In practice, they're an address of those variables, that will likely be generated by adding some compile-time-known offset to the base or stack pointer, with the address being generated at run-time.

Comment: The `&` operator creates pointers, just like the `+` operator adds numbers, and the unary `-` operator negates numbers.  So if I call `f(&a, b+c, -d)`, the `&`, `+`, and `-` operators all do their work at more or less the same time, as the arguments to the function call are being prepared.

Comment: @SteveSummit The `&` operator *creates* pointers?

Comment: @CinCout: Certainly, as much as the `*` operator creates the product `20` in `4*5`. In either case, `4*5` or `&a`, the result is merely a value (a number, letter, address, or other element of a set of things of some kind) not an object (a region of storage whose contents can represent values), but that value is produced as a result of the operator.

Comment: @CinCout Or "generates" pointers.  That's the way I tend to thing about it, anyway, in a higher-level way.  Now, it's true, depending on what `a` and `b` are, their address are what their addresses are, and (as other comments have pointed out) there may be no real work to "create" them.  (If `a` has static duration, for example, `f(&a)` basically just passes a constant to `f`, albeit a link-time constant.)  But given that `a` and `b` are local variables, the compiler is going to have to emit actual code to add their offsets to the current stack/frame pointer before passing them to `swap()`.

Comment: "To generate a pointer" means "to cause a pointer to come into existence", and so does "to create a pointer". I personally use "evaluates to" when talking about operators, but "produces" and "returns" and also used. You may have a preference of verb, but all of these are synonymous, so this quibbling doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 3):

The pointers to `a` and `b` are created as results of evaluation of argument expressions in the function call

```
swap(&a, &b);
     ^^  ^^
```

From the C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand.

Thus the expressions `&a` and `&b` have the type `int *` and yield the addresses of the variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: In terms of C this is accurate. But at a lower level the pointers existed all along, not the types they reference. Instead of creating new variables to serve as pointers for the & operation results, it simply uses the pointers that were made available when the stackframe was created.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner You are wrong. The compiler cares about the & operator and generates the  corresponding object code.

Comment: I didn't imply that it didn't. Perhaps that was worded poorly. Yes in this case the compiler uses the load effective address (lea) instruction instead of the move (mov) instruction. This certainly has an impact, but with regards to the OP's question it does not "create" a pointer. The pointer exists and the variable doesn't, so to speak.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner: I do not see any model or level—whether the C abstract computer model or the instructions in an actual computer or other—in which the pointer necessarily exists prior to evaluation of the `&` operator. Suppose the stack pointer is currently 2400, and `a` is located 12 bytes above that. Just before the `&` is evaluated by executing an `lea` instruction, there might be no place in the computer where the value 2412 exists—no register, memory, or other bits containing 2412. After the `lea` executes, 2412 is in a register. The `lea` instruction creates this pointer.

Comment: "Suppose the stack pointer is current 2400, and `a` is located 12 bytes above that..." - Then all references to `a` technically dereference `a` at 2400+12. This dereference requires the original pointer. I think the confusion here is we are talking about two different things. To access any data, we need to know where they reside. A direct access to `a` in one way or another uses a pointer to where it is stored, perhaps indirectly.

Comment: I see what you are saying though. I'm talking about where the data is stored. You are talking about where a reference to that storage location is created. I think this answer addresses the OP's question sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that `a` and `b` are created, this essentially means that a chunk of memory is assigned to these variables, which is then initialized with the respective values. Those memory chunks have an address. The pointers in `swap()` are nothing but the addresses in memory where `a` and `b` are stored.

Comment: not entirely true, a variable that does not have its address taken need not have an address! It is even so that the address-of operator might be the very reason for the variable having an address at *all*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In the model used by the C standard, every object has an address. In an actual implementation, an object does not need to be implemented using storage and hence need not have an address. If a person is writing about the semantics as defined by the C standard, it is a correct statement to say that `a` and `b` have memory reserved for them and have addresses; this statement is entirely true.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil That‘s not 100% correct. Menbers of bitfields don‘t have adresses. But I guess that is mainly an issue when developing HW drivers.

Comment: @Drunix: Fine, but the objects under discussion are not bit-fields.

Answer (score 1):

All variables are stored at addresses in memory. Therefore, there exists a pointer for each variable you declare, even if you do not declare them as pointers. To understand what is actually happening it helps to know the basics of assembly language. The following is the relevant part of your code compiled in x86_64 and viewed via `objdump`.

```
6ee:    c7 45 f0 03 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x3
6f5:    c7 45 f4 05 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x5
6fc:    48 8d 55 f4             lea    rdx,[rbp-0xc]
700:    48 8d 45 f0             lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]
704:    48 89 d6                mov    rsi,rdx
707:    48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
70a:    e8 9b ff ff ff          call   6aa <swap>
```

At lines 0x6ee and 0x6f5 your variables are initialized. Notice that in this case they are actually stored on the stackframe at rbp-0x10 and rbp-0xc respectively. On the following two lines, the addresses of these variables are stored into registers rdx and rax, respectively, then moved into the appropriate registers (rsi and rdi) so that they can be passed the the swap function.

To summarize, C is written at a higher level than the machine architecture that actually executes your code. In machine languages, variables are stored at locations in memory, which are accessible through pointers in the form of offsets to registers, memory sections, etc. In the example above you can see that the data 3 and 5 were "stored in pointer locations" the entire time.

Comment: All good info, but I think the jest of the question was for the function parameters. In that sense, the reference to the address would be created by use of the *address of* operator `&` when used in the call to `swap(&a, &b);` passing to `swap` the addresses where `a` and `b` are located in memory. Good explanation on where and how those addresses come to be.

Comment: Sure, I think that explanation is sufficient to answer the OP's question. Here I attempt to provide some lower level details to help clarify what is actually happening. I interpreted the question as, "Are pointers to the variables created after the `&` operation. Technically, no. But if the question is about C syntax and behavior, then the explanation you provided works well.

Comment: You make a really good point that few think about, that even the declaration of a variable with an immediate value, such as `int a = 3;` is really nothing more than the creation of a label to the memory location where the value is stored. That is the benefit understanding assembly brings.